# Algorithmic programming based on strings

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a set of 10 symbols and a set of strings(at max 100) of length at max 20 each consisting  of these symbols, find the maximum length string which can be made from these symbols that doesn't have any of the given strings as its sub-string. In case, if we can have infinite long string satisfying the property, print -1.

Besides brute force algorithm which will go exponential in time, I am not able to get any solution for this.

Any hint to approach this problem will be thankful.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Go do your homework, try something on your own and come back if you got further questions regarding a specific problem in your implementation.

Comment: Isn't there *always* an infintely long string that satisfies those properties? Just avoid completely copying any of the substrings. Even a single repeating character could count as an infinite output string, assuming none of the given strings are the same.

Comment: @akluth : This is not a homework problem, I got this problem in a coding contest and I am just asking for hints on how to approach it algorithmically.

Comment: I'm not up to a rigorous proof, but I suspect the algorithm `print -1` would probably suffice... Proof would probably start with the observation that 100 strings of length 20 would only cover a (very small) subset of all possible substrings, of which there are in excess of 10^20, so there are plenty of substrings left over that do not exist in your test set, and which can be used to construct an input string...

Comment: @geobits: No, it will be not always. e.g. if you have only two symbols 0 and 1 and four strings 101, 111, 00, 110, then the longest string possible will be not of infinite length, you can try it.

Comment: Ah. So you meant 10 symbols **max**, not "a set of 10 symbols". For ten symbols, there can be 10^10 possibilities, which 100 "given" strings can't possibly cover.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of strings that need to be matched, my immediate reaction is to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm to create a matcher. This matcher is a finite state machine that accepts one character at a time and tells you which state you end up in next, given that character.

So I think you can reduce the problem to accepting a directed graph and a starting point and finding the longest route through that graph that does not go through the nodes that correspond to pattern matches - which I think we can simply delete from the graph. This is covered in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path. Constructing this graph is also linear so the whole thing seems to be O(n)